# Can I start networking using XP's "Safe Mode with Command Prompt"?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, command-line-interface, safe-mode

In XP, is it possible to start up networking (similar to Safe Mode with Networking) while logged in via the "Safe Mode with Command Prompt" option?

I tried **net start "network connections"** but this says it cannot be started in Safe Mode. Any other ideas?

FYI, Safe Mode with Networking is not an option in this case, due to UI restrictions preventing the use of a command prompt or the Run command in anything other than Safe Mode with Command Prompt.

Comment: Not that it matters, since the question was answered already -- but, "closed as off topic"? Really? It's desktop support related for a "Business Workstation operating systems" as outlined in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can - the networking subsystem and drivers are not loaded, and they can't be started.

With Safe Mode with Networking, have you tried browsing to the CMD.exe file and double clicking it?  Have you tried copying and renaming the file to something else then executing it?

Comment: No browse capability either. It's a limited GUI, even in Safe Mode.

Comment: Is there a way to load subsystems after boot?

Comment: +1 and accepted -- So far there is no known way to do this. It's the correct answer even if I don't like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, because safe mode is slimmed down as much as possible. Default drivers are loaded and anything extra is not loaded.  I am not sure safe mode even initiates the default network card drivers unless you are in the safe mode with networking.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said you won't be able to do it.

My suggestion would be to launch into Safe mode with networking and then create a batch file that uses the runat command to launch cmd.exe. Set runat to run cmd.exe 5 mins from now and wait. A Dos box should pop and you'll have networking and a command prompt. Sorry i can't give you the exact command my xp box is in the middle of reinstalling windows right now.

Answer (score 0):

Would what you want to do better be suited to a bootable [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) or Windows PE CD/DVD?  You can then have networking and access to your disks.

Comment: Unfortunately, those options are not available.